# Fire ng-change event for textbox other than keypress or keydown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I want to update a text value when the value is changed by using some method, the method should not call when I am still typing text but when exit from the textbox or change it through script code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model ="model.value" ng-change = "update()"/>
```

what should contain update() method,

what I tried is : wrote a directive for this textbox, and

```
scope.$watch('model', function(nval,oval){
   if ((oVal === undefined) && (nVal != undefined)){
     update()
   }
});
```

It is calling for the first time, but not whenever the model value changed.

I want to call update method whenever the model.value changed, but not while entering text

Comment: you can try using `$scope.$apply()` after update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-ng-model-options directly to achieve your requirement.
Like,

here you can get full reference of data-ng-nmodel-options
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

this directive will work for the versions angular 1.4.x ( from 1.4.x version it suppports)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-blur` and you should change your `$watch`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/bagLk3kq/2)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.value" ng-blur="update()"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        value: 'hello'
    };
    $scope.update = function () {
        console.log("changed!");
    };
    $scope.$watch('model.value', function (nval, oval) {
        if (oval !== nval) {
            $scope.update();
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: even model.value will be changed from other methods too, that is the case i am missing, update should not call when focus is on textbox